# Interleave.el opens pdf in Fundamental

Tags: org-mode

I got the [interleave](https://github.com/rudolfochrist/interleave) package up and running and started using it. Now I try to `M-x interleave` a new document from the org file and it tries to open the document in new file Fundamental mode buffer instead of the pdf that exists on path with DocView.

Same happens when I do `M-x interleave--open-notes-file-for-pdf` on an already open pdf in DocView, when the org file of the same basename exists with the `#+INTERLEAVE_PDF: ./basename` already present.

However, my old interleaved documents (for which I wrote the header) still work both ways. And I can create an org file (that ends up creating the same header as if I would write it) from an open pdf by `M-x interleave--open-notes-file-for-pdf` with `interleave-org-notes-dir-list` set to only `.` or, puzzlingly an `i` (for insert entry for this page into notes) even when the pdf buffer only reports being in DocView mode. After that it behaves as expected.

Anyone have any ideas on how different behaviors like this could exist simultaneously? I thought that the interleaved information was contained in the org file only.

Comment: Do you reference the absolute path to the pdf in the .org file using something like this: `#+INTERLEAVE_PDF: /the/path/to/pdf.pdf`?

Comment: `M-x interleave--open-notes-file-for-pdf` will work based on the value in `interleave-org-notes-dir-list` var. Check the docstring of that var using `C-h v`. This too works fine for me.

Comment: I tried both relative and absolute as well as checking `interleave-org-notes-dir-list`. When I do absolute it doesn't even recognize that the directories exist.

Comment: The only thing I can remember changing was the `doc-view-resolution` variable but reverting to default and `M-x doc-view-clear-cache` didn't help

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have in your setup related to the `interleave` package? Which variables are you customizing and what are their values? If you are comfortable with elisp, also try [edebug](http://endlessparentheses.com/debugging-emacs-lisp-part-1-earn-your-independence.html)ging `interleave--open-notes-file-for-pdf`.

Comment: I use `pdf-tools` instead of `doc-view` and I don't think the variables you mentioned affect `interleave`. You have problem opening the pdf linked to its interleaved notes org file, right?

Comment: I have updated it to some new findings and I now have at least something that works. I think your suggestion just to debug the elisp is the best idea, considering the behavior I am getting. It's just something I don't know how to do at this point. Thanks for your help maybe I'll figure it out in the future when I have time to learn elisp properly.